# Android native strong pointer vs std::shared_ptr

Tags: android, c++, c++11, std, native

I'm referring to [Refbase.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-dev/include/utils/RefBase.h), [Refbase.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-mr1-release/libs/utils/RefBase.cpp) and [StrongPointer.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/android-4.2.2_r1/include/utils/StrongPointer.h)

In the Android implementation of strong pointer, any strong-pointer based object must inherit refbase i.e.

```
sp<TheClass> theObj // TheClass must inherit from class RefBase
```

This requirement can be seen in the code for one of `sp`'s methods:

```
template<typename T> sp<T>& sp<T>::operator =(T* other) {
    if (other != NULL) {
        other->incStrong(this);
    }
    if (mPtr != NULL) {
        mPtr->decStrong(this);
    }
    mPtr = other;
    return *this; 
}
```

In order for call to `incStrong` or `decStrong` to not fail . . . `other` and `mPtr` must have inherited `RefBase`

**QUESTION**

Why is `sp` implemented such that the obj that it's managing is *required* to be a child of `RefBase`? There's not even a way to enforce this requirement at compile-time or even runtime. (Well maybe `if(type()...`)

[Std library doesn't have such a requirement](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/)

...
Upon further thought, is the answer that this provides flexibility?
If yes, how does this provide flexibility?

Answer (score 2):

It saves a memory allocation. When you write:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo{new Foo(bar)};
```

`pFoo` actually has a pointer to a shared data structure (allocated on the heap), which has the reference counters, and the pointer to the actual Foo object.  By making objects be derived from `RefBase`, you can embed the reference counts in the object itself (saving the additional memory allocation).

Interestingly, with C++11 onwards, you can avoid the additional memory allocation by using `std::make_shared<Foo>` which will do a single memory allocation and construct the shared data structure and the Foo object in it.

The fact there is no compile time checking of the derivation from `RefBase` is carelessness.  `m_ptr` should have been declared as `RefBase *m_ptr`, and then `operator *` (etc) should have done a static_cast to `T*`.  In fact, I would probably have made `sp<T>` inherit from `sp_base` which had the comparison operators as public, and the other functions as protected.

**Edit**

On second thoughts, there *is* quite a bit of compile time checking.  If `T` doesn't have an `incStrong` member, the compilation will fail, and it *almost* certainly won't unless it derives from `RefBase`.  I still think converting a  `T*` to a `RefBase*` would have been a *better* check, but the one that is there is probably good enough.

Comment: Are you sure your example is legal for `shared_ptr`? [The assignment operator only takes special pointers.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/operator=/) For class`sp`, that assignment **is** legal.

Comment: I don't show an assignment operator - I showed an initialization.  If you want to do an assignment with shared_ptr it would have to be:  `pFoo=shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(bar));`

Comment: ... and that is the other advantage of an intrusive pointer.  (and you don't have to play silly games with `shared_from_this`).

Comment: ... but of course you can't have an `sp` to an int, or a POD, or whatever.

Comment: [None of these initialization methods show using the `=` operator is valid](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/)

Comment: It's not a usage of the assignment operator, but that doesn't mean this is valid (which it isn't). [Simply try it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f18e260f9f365cb0).

Comment: Thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit - you are quite right.

Answer (score 0):

It automatically allows you to create sp from any object implementing RefBase, while for shared pointer you can shoot yourself in the foot while trying to wrap raw pointer into shared one.

So while for shared_ptr you might need this:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

for sp you can almost safely pass raw pointer to sp contructor.