# std::shared_ptr - can I use equal sign (=) for initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

From my reading of [the `std::shared_ptr` doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/), you cannot use `=` to initialize the `shared_ptr` from an existing pointer.

If you wish to initialize from existing pointer, the only syntax available is
`std::shared_ptr<int> p3 (new int);`

**QUESTION**

Is it correct that you cannot use `=` to initialize a `shared_ptr` as in the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo = new Foo(bar);
```

Someone else (with more experience in C++ than me) [has stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42142680/4784683) that you can.

Comment: He is wrong, the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) in use is marked `explicit`

Comment: What is not valid is the implicit conversion from `Foo*`. But this is OK: `std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(bar));`

Comment: @juanchopanza yes I agree. I was more focusing on [his statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42142680/4784683) that using `=` was ***initialization*** vs ***assignment***

Comment: The preferred way is `std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo = std::make_shared<Foo>(bar);`.

Comment: `=` isn't assignment here.

Comment: @juanchopanza why not?

Comment: @Adrian: I concur with WhiZTiM. That guy is wrong. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f18e260f9f365cb0

Comment: It is an initialization, not an assignment. That's just the way it is defined.

Comment: @Adrian: Because it isn't. It's copy-initialisation. An assignment operator is never called during declaration/definition, regardless of the use of the token/symbol `=`.

Comment: @juanchopanza ok but which constructor is called in this case (using `=`). Is it the copy constructor? If yes, how would one know this from the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/). I don't see any use of the `=` sign.

Comment: @Adrian It isn't a special constructor, it is C++ grammar. It requires that a copy constructor exist, but usually no actual copying takes place (there's this thing called *copy elision*.)

Comment: I have corrected the answer at hand, and now we can all move on :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot initialize `std::shared_ptr` that way because the single argument [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) is marked `explicit`.

You can however initialize it using any of:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo(new Foo(bar));                         //direct-initialization
std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo{new Foo(bar)};                         //direct-list-initialization
```

Or:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(bar));  //copy-initialization
std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>{new Foo(bar)};  //copy-initialization
```

Better still use [`std::make_shared<Foo>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) which *usually* does [a single allocation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared#Notes):

```
auto pFoo = std::make_shared<Foo>(bar);
```

Comment: Or `std::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo{new Foo(bar)};`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize a `std::shared_ptr` using syntax such as

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p3 = new int;
```

because the constructor is marked explicit [[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)]

```
template <class Y>
explicit shared_ptr(Y* ptr);
```

and initialization in this form involves the *implicit* conversion of the right-hand side into `shared_ptr<int>`, and an implicit conversion is not allowed to call an explicit constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: the syntax is illegal. The third constructor in the documentation you linked to is marked `explicit`, which means that a properly conforming compiler and Standard Library implementation will not allow something like `std::shared_ptr<int> int_ptr = new int(5);`.

It is possible that the user in question is *not* using a properly conforming compiler/library, or may be used to a hand-rolled shared_pointer object which doesn't have this restriction.